# Call a C varargs function from Java through JNA

Tags: variadic-functions, jna, calling-convention

By the looks of [these past issues](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues?q=vararg) and [this documentation](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Function.html#invoke-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object:A-java.util.Map-) it appears doable, But how ?

My trials:

C

```
extern "C" GATEWAY_API void callIntoNative(LPCSTR evt_name, ...);


void callIntoNative(LPCSTR evt_name, ...)
//void callIntoNative(char* evt_name)
{
    std::cout << evt_name << std::endl;
    va_list vargs;
    va_start(vargs, evt_name);
    std::cout << va_arg(vargs, int) << "   " << va_arg(vargs, double) << std::endl;
    va_end(vargs);
}
```

Java

```
  // public static native void callIntoNative(String evtName, Object[] varargs);
  //  public static native void callIntoNative(String evtName, Object... varargs);
//GateWay.callIntoNative("give me love", new Object[] {24, new String()});

Function callIntoNative = Function.getFunction("gateway.dll", "callIntoNative");
callIntoNative.invoke(new Object[]{new String("give me love"), new Integer(24), new Double(3.14)});
```

The output from Java program:

```
give me love
1374389535   1.18576e-322
```